# How to avoid two similar CTE definitions

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-tuning

I have a report which uses a dozen of CTEs and takes awfuly long to execute. Thing is that a lot of those CTEs use the same tables, joined in the same way, but on different conditions, depending on the column:

```
    WITH
Kps_CTE (sp_id,ksd_ma_s) As
    (
        select wir_sp_id,SUM(ksd_ma)
            from ksd
            inner join ks on ksd_ks_id=ks_id 
            inner join do ON ksd_do_id=do_id AND do_dot_id in (101)
            inner join wi ON do_wi_id=wi_id 
            inner join wir ON wir_wi_id=wi_id
            INNER JOIN sp ON wir_sp_id=sp_id
            where ksd_ksk_id=13
                AND sp_date >= '2013-01-01'
            group by wir_sp_id
    ),      
    Kis_CTE (sp_id,ksd_wn_s) As
    (
        select wir_sp_id,SUM(ksd_wn)
            from ksd
            inner join ks on ksd_ks_id=ks_id 
            inner join do ON ksd_do_id=do_id AND do_dot_id in (4)
            inner join wi ON do_wi_id=wi_id 
            inner join wir ON wir_wi_id=wi_id
            INNER JOIN sp ON wir_sp_id=sp_id
            where ksd_ksk_id=14
                AND sp_date>= '2013-01-01'
            group by wir_sp_id
    )


 select * from ...
```

So right now I get only two columns per each table. I would like to avoid joining the same tables all over again and create a few columns in one CTE using different conditions. Is this possible? If I just join these two I won't save much resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to describe what you are doing with these CTEs. Perhaps this can figure out your case:

```
;WITH Kps_CTE (sp_id,ksd_ma_s) As
(
    select wir_sp_id,
      SUM(case when ksd_ksk_id=13 then ksd_ma end) as KPS, 
      Sum(case when ksd_ksk_id=14 then ksd_wn end) as KIS, 
    from ksd
    inner join ks on ksd_ks_id=ks_id 
    inner join do ON ksd_do_id=do_id 
    inner join wi ON do_wi_id=wi_id 
    inner join wir ON wir_wi_id=wi_id
    INNER JOIN sp ON wir_sp_id=sp_id
    where (ksd_ksk_id=13 AND do_dot_id = 101
        OR ksd_ksk_id=14 and do_dot_id = 4)
      AND sp_date >= '2013-01-01'
    group by wir_sp_id
),
```

If `OR` list is big - it may be converted into another CTE with list of tuples `(ksd_ksk_id; do_dot_id)`, then joined.

Not sure why you are having all those magic numbers in the query, won't be surprised if finally we'll find out that you actually need `PIVOT`or something.